# Do not show the data if there is no role Admin

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables many to many relation. Any user can have multiple roles, I don't want to display user that has role = 'Admin', issue is if it has multiple roles it will be displayed.

```
[User]      [Role]    [UserRole]
UserId      RoleId      UserId
FirstName   RoleName    RoleId
LastName
```

Right not I have this query `SELECT FirstName, LastName, RoleName FROM User JOIN UserRole ON UserRole.UserId = User.UserId JOIN Role ON Role.RoleId = UserRole.RoleId WHERE RoleName != 'Admin'`

Example:
User **A** has role **Admin** and **Manager**, my query will display manager, but I don't want to show any user that has role **Admin**

Comment: An answer has been provided but, if you're still struggling, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with subselects:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, RoleName 
FROM User 
INNER JOIN UserRole 
ON UserRole.UserId = User.UserId 
INNER JOIN Role 
ON Role.RoleId = UserRole.RoleId 
WHERE User.UserId NOT IN 
    (SELECT UserId
     FROM UserRole AS ur
     WHERE ur.RoleId = (SELECT RoleId FROM Role AS rn WHERE rn.RoleName = 'Admin')
    )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aadae3/2

Comment: WOW I tried with not exist but selecting the firstname and lastname, and forgot about ID. Big Thanks. Please edit in subselect FROM RoleName in Role